# google maps javascript api return lat and lng

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been looking at the code for the autocomplete address form on the google developers sample page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-gdl#style_autocomplete

All I'm trying to do is extract the latitude and longitude values of the autofilled address and save them as variables to use later in the script. I'm pretty new to javascript and don't seem to be able to get my head round this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `place.geometry.location`  which is a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) object.

This has functions .lat() and .lng() you can use, e.g. you could do:

```
var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Or:

```
var coords = place.geometry.location.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to get the latitude and longitude without resorting to the geolocation Api, you could inspect the map.getBounds(). The code would be similar to the following:

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);
```

And then:

```
var result = map.getBounds();
```

Comment: This about the Autocomplete Service, I don't think your answer addresses the question.